# Node.js : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm having problems in connecting my node.js application with mysql database. I have gotten the error below:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I did a little digging and found these test for connection:

First code:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
```

I tested the above code and it will prompt out the password and gave me the access to it.

Second code:

```
mysql -u root -p -h > localhost -P 3306
```

I tested the above code and gotten an access is denied

From my understanding, correct me if I'm wrong, localhost == 127.0.0.1. So what is the reason for one of them not having access since they are the same?

Please help me. I've been stuck on this for hours. Thank you for your time.

My node.js code for login (not finished):

```
module.exports = function(app,passport){

    let mysql = require('mysql');
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '9@v62STH9J',
        database: 'fyp',
        port: 3306
    });

    connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            return console.log('error: ' + err.message);
        }
        console.log("connected.");
    });

    app.get('/login', function(req,res){
        res.render('loginpage', {message:req.flash('loginMessage')});
    })

    app.post('/login', function(req,res){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM user", function (err, result, field){
            if (err){
                return console.log('error: ' + err.message);
            }
            Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key){
                row = result[key];
                if(row.u_username == req.body.username){
                    if(row.u_password == req.body.password){
                        console.log("in");
                        res.redirect('/' + row.u_id +'/home');
                    }
                    // else{
                    //     // res.send('wrong');
                    //     console.log("here");
                    //     res.render('loginpage', {result: 'Incorrect password is entered.'});
                    // }
                }
                // else{
                //     console.log("here2");
                //     // console.log(typeof req.next);
                //     res.render('loginpage', {result: "Username is not found in the database."});
                // }
            });
        });
    });

    app.get('/logout', function(req,res){
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/login');
    })
};
```

the main node.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    util = require('util');
    mysql = require('mysql');
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
require('./controllers/user')(passport);

var compController = require('./controllers/compController');
var patController = require('./controllers/patController');
var taskController = require('./controllers/taskController');
var loginController = require('./controllers/loginController');
var staffController = require('./controllers/staffController');
var checkController = require('./controllers/checkController');
var repController = require('./controllers/repController');
var homeController = require('./controllers/homeController');
var noticeController = require('./controllers/noticeController');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));
app.use('/js', express.static('js'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, secret: 'sarah', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}))
app.use(flash());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// require('./controllers/loginController')(app,passport);

compController(app);
patController(app);
taskController(app);
staffController(app);
checkController(app);
repController(app);
homeController(app);
loginController(app);
noticeController(app);

// app.use((req,res,next) => {
//   var err = new Error('Page not found');
//   err.status = 404;
//   next(err);
// });

// app.use((err,req,res,next) => {
//   res.status(err.status || 500);
//   res.send(err.message);
// })

app.listen(3003, 'localhost', function(){
  console.log("Working");
});
```

Comment: @num8er I have put the node.js code inside the question. Thank you for your help

Comment: Try `host: '127.0.0.1'`  cause for mysql `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are different records in `mysql.user` table which is responsible for db user creds.

Comment: @num8er the problem is still happening. What should I do?

Comment: try this also: `const connection = mysql.createConnection('mysql://root:9%40v62STH9J@127.0.0.1:3306/fyp');`

Comment: As I see from Your code where You create connection, it's correct. I think You've other places in Your code where You've not passed password in connection. Otherwise it needs debugging, cause it has to work the way You already did.

Comment: @tkzlskg try mysql2 modules. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2

Comment: why do you have > in the command line? The command will end there

Comment: Are you sure your error message comes from the code you showed us? The message says you tried to connect to your MySql server without specifying a password.

Comment: Never use user root user for you application. Its not safe. You should to create separate user with enough permissions and use it into your code.